# Error when compiling shared object: C++ class definition not being detected

Tags: c++, linux

I'm trying to compile a shared library that will be used as a plugin to some testing software I am writing that will check the viability of navigational algorithms for a robot.  The testing software loads a shared object containing the definition of an object representing an implementation of a navigation algorithm, as well as a factory method to generate said object.  The software then uses this object to test the algorithm's viability under known conditions. In a nutshell, the software is going to give the algorithm a starting point and a reference to a representation of the course before handing over the reigns.  But all this is beside the point.

Right now, I am trying to compile a stub library just to check/debug the shared object loading mechanisms.  Below are the header files I am using:

Course.hpp:

```
    /*********************************
     * Filename: Course.hpp
     * Purpose: Defines and clarifies
     * ALL data of or relating to the
     * physical course. itself.
     *
     * NOTE: The default number of obstacles is 3.
     */

    #ifndef COURSE_HPP_
    #define COURSE_HPP_

    namespace LunarBot{

    #define COURSE_ROWS 388
    #define COURSE_COLUMNS 738
    typedef char MapPoint; /*Container for flags. 8-bit for size*/
    /*By this, the total size of our array will be about 279.63 KB*/


    //Simple structure for representing map coordinates:
    typedef struct{
        int x;
        int y;
    }MapAddr;

    /*Define Obstacle Base Class:*/
    #define OBSTACLE_TYPE_CRATER 0x00
    #define OBSTACLE_TYPE_ROCK 0x01

    class Obstacle {
        //Class fields:
    public: MapPoint currCourse[COURSE_ROWS][COURSE_COLUMNS];

        //Class Methods:
    public:
        //Constructor:
        Obstacle(MapPoint ourCourse[COURSE_ROWS][COURSE_COLUMNS]);

        //Destructor:
        ~Obstacle();
    };

    /*Define Course:*/
    class Course{
        //Class fields:
    public: MapPoint ourCourse[COURSE_ROWS][COURSE_COLUMNS];
    private: //Unknown, as of this point.
             Obstacle allObstacles[];

        //Class methods:
    public:
        //Constructor:
    Course(bool fullAuto);
    Course(bool fullAuto, int numObstacles);

    //Destructor:
    ~Course();

private:
    //Initialization Methods:
    void initializeObstacles(int); //Randomly place as many obstacles as possible up to the number requested.
    MapAddr randomizeStartPoint();
};

}// end namespace LunarBot
#endif /* COURSE_HPP_ */
```

NaviAlgorithm.hpp:

```
/************************************
 * Filename: NaviAlgorithm.hpp
 * Purpose: This file defines the
 * NaviAlgorithm class which must
 * be subclassed by ALL classes
 * representing different and diverse
 * navigation algorithms.
 *
 * This class declares two very important functions,
 * "startNavigation()" and "startNavigationWithStepThrough()".
 *
 * Both perform the same navigational tasks.  The difference lies
 * in when and what type of output is sent to the console.
 *
 * "startNavigation()", after being called. Outputs nothing to the
 * console until the simulated robot has successfully completed its task.
 * When this occurs, the measured completion time is displayed.
 *
 * "startNavigationWithStepThrough()", as the name suggests, allows
 * the user to step through each stage as the robot navigates its way
 * around the simulated course. Output occurs at certain points during the
 * simulation. When these points occur is dependent on the algorithm implemented.
 * What is standardized, to an extent, however, is WHAT is output.
 *
 * This function will ALWAYS output ANY AND ALL related environmental variables
 * (locations of nearby obstacles, time elapsed since last output, etc.).  As
 * a rule of thumb, if you can't determine the algorithm's effectiveness without something, make sure
 * you know what that something is.  For you and for us that means include it in the periodic series of outputs.
 * For your convenience, a virtual function for that purpose has been provided.
 *
 ************************************/

#ifndef NAVIALGORITHM_HPP_
#define NAVIALGORITHM_HPP_

namespace LunarBot{

#include "Course.hpp"

#define ROBOT_POSITION_FLAG 0x80

class NaviAlgorithm{
    //Class Fields:
public: Course* currentCourse;
private: char** argsArray;
    //Class Methods:
public:
    //Constructor:
    NaviAlgorithm(Course* c);
    NaviAlgorithm(Course* c, char** args);  //A mechanism is in place that you may provide arguments to your algorithm from the command line, if you like.

    //Begin Simulation Sequence:
    virtual void startNavigation();
    virtual void startNavigationWithStepThrough();

    //Destructor:
    virtual ~NaviAlgorithm();
};

/*Factory Method:*/
extern "C" NaviAlgorithm* createAlgorithmObject(Course* c){
    return new NaviAlgorithm(c);
}
}

#endif /* NAVIALGORITHM_HPP_ */
```

And, here are the ".cpp" files I am currently using:

```
#include "NaviAlgorithm.hpp"
#include <cstdlib>
#include <iostream>
using std::cout;

namespace LunarBot{
//************************
// Function Definitions:
//************************

//************************
// Constructors:
//************************
NaviAlgorithm::NaviAlgorithm(Course* course){
    currentCourse = course;
    argsArray = NULL;
}

NaviAlgorithm::NaviAlgorithm(Course* course, char** args){
    currentCourse = course;
    argsArray = args;
}

//*************************
// Destructor:
//*************************
NaviAlgorithm::~NaviAlgorithm(){
    cout << "Default destructor\n";
}

//*************************
// Navigation Methods:
//*************************
void NaviAlgorithm::startNavigation(){
    cout << "Navigation started;\n";
}

void NaviAlgorithm::startNavigationWithStepThrough(){
    cout << "Navigation started;\n";
}
```

};

My problem is that whenever I try to build the shared object, the compiler always gives me the error "Course does not name a type" for both NaviAlgorithm.hpp and NaviAlgorithm.cpp.  Is there something I am missing? The program, as a whole, is being built to run on Linux only. Any suggestions would be appreciated.

Comment: Looks like it is not seeing Course.hpp file. Make sure your Makefile includes that either as a path "-I" or by directly having it within the same folder.

Comment: @AbhiP Wouldnt that already cause an include-error in the preprocessor phase?

Comment: That's when forward declarations are helpful. Looking at your code, it does not utilize anything from inside course.hpp file so just forward declare in your NaviAlgorithm.hpp file, instead of including it. 
E.g.: "class Course;"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In file NaviAlgorithm.hpp,

```
namespace LunarBot{
#include "Course.hpp"
```

Change this to as below:-

```
#include "Course.hpp"
namespace LunarBot{
```

Otherwise you are creating new namespace LunarBot inside namespace LunarBot.

Comment: I apologize for taking so long to answer back.  I have been very busy as of late, but that fixed the problem.  Thanks!

Comment: Ok. Good to know that your issue is fixed by the changes.